# how to reset listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view in this activity

First, i will display list view with this

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter_LatestNews(this, title, category, date,
            imagepath);     

lv.addFooterView(constant.AdMob());
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am using custom adapter which extend base adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

In this activity, i have a refresh button which was update data and call back same activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Main_AllLatestNews.this, Main_AllLatestNews.class));
finish();
```

It seem like the getview is reusing the data?

Before press refresh button

> result > image 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 correct display (no matter how i scroll)

After press refresh button

> result > image 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 incorrect display (scroll will cause this)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried this? ListView.invalidate();

Comment: nothing happen, still the same after i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way to refresh list view is not by restarting the activity.

instead - after refreshing the logic list /or the data the adapter working with, all you need to do is to call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: don't have this function, only got `notify()` and `notifyall()`

Comment: are you using derived class from base adapter?

Comment: so check again, cause I'm sure 100% this method exists -  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i know why i cannot get, i use wrong variable. i was using lv instead of adapter.

Comment: I call this `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after 5 second but it does not reset the list

Comment: @Alan Lai: as I wrote in my answer - restart the activity is not the solution if you did so, and won't help.   notifyDataSetChanged() takes affect if the logic data which been used by the adapter has changed. so your "refresh" method need actually to refresh the data which been used by the adapter, and afterward - call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @Alan Lai: if what I'm saying not working for you - you probably have another problems in your code. add to the question's body your full activity and adapter code if you want them to be reviewd

Comment: I added `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but do i need include call again `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`?

Comment: @Alan Lai: the answer is basically - no.          lv.setAdapter(adapter) can be useful to be call again only if you need the list view to show diffrent type of data from what it held before.  in that case - the new adapter you'll set would probably have a diffrent implementation

Comment: actually i got 2 buttons, more and refresh. More is add the size of list from 10 to 20 30 40 50 whereas refresh is refresh the size list into original 10

Comment: @Alan Lai: I'll say it on the third time:  add items to the data list / remove / clear / change complitly are all operations that changes the logic list the adapter working with, so afterward you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() if you want the changes to take affect.     I've got tired from your question.. if you want help - you need to provide good question to what exactly your problem, or at least attach the source code

Answer (score 2):

You Could try & it worked for me:

**Initialization of the list view and adapter:**

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
adapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Reset the list and the adapter array:**

```
listView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
listMessages.clear();
```